# Promise.all with node package

Tags: node.js, promise

hello im using a node package which uses promises.

I want to return all promises resolved together in one array, I heard you can do this with promise.all. 
But i am not sure how to implement it in my case.

I have this so far :

```
const characters = ['yoda','luke skywalker' ,'R2-D2']; 


client.search(<A CHARACTER FROM THE CHARACTER ARRAY>, options)
    .then(images => {
        console.log(images)
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

What i tried to do :

```
const characters = ['yoda','luke skywalker' , 'R2-D2']

    Promise.all(characters.map(char => {
      client.search(char, options)
        .then(images => {
            console.log(images)
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    })).then(data => {
      console.log(data);
    })
```

but data returns [ undefined, undefined, undefined ]
images does return something tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to supply an array of promises into promises.all, do not evaluate them. Try this

```js
Promise.all(characters.map(char => client.search(char, options)))
.then(data => {
  console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: still [undefined undefined undefined], but a single one works.

Comment: did you try my updated answer? Just edited it 1 minute ago

Comment: Yeah that's what i figured. With the curly braces included, the promises weren't getting returned from the map function